# My app stalls when using WIFI on IOS 12.1

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

My APP (xamarin.forms for IOS) does not connect to the server via WIFI. Is it necessary to add a key in the Entitlements.plist?

(it's my first APP for IOS ...)

Comment: No, it is needed only when your app access WIFI information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for the information. APPLE mistakenly informed me of a problem with WIFI during the acceptance phase of my APP. The problem is instead due to the lack of data on the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to add a key in the Entitlements.plist?

**No.**

I'd check the URL that you're using, and also try just loading some content from an URL that you know works. Also, of course, verify that the device can connect in general — try using Safari to load a page.